# Why is html page sent by express.js route not connected to a css stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

So I have server.js file that imports a router

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(require('./app/routing/htmlRoutes'));
```

The router looks like this

```
const path = require("path");
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();



router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('home.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
});

router.get('/survey', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('survey.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
});


module.exports = router;
```

It does work! It renders html pages, however those html pages have css stylesheets hooked up to them and located in the same directory, but they render as blank html sheets (unstyled)...
How do I make them render with css stylesheets taken into account?

Comment: Where do you serve those css files?

Comment: In the same directory as html files ... 'public'

Comment: You meant where do I store them?

Comment: No, I meant where/how do you serve them. Your script serves two html files, but not the css files, so it obiously fails with a 404 when your browser tries to load them.

Comment: So do I have to serve them as well? They wouldn't be automatically linked up to the html (since they are in the head tag)?

Comment: Yes, you need to serve them aswell. Express doesn't wire them up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When the browser encounters the style reference of the loaded html file, it tries to load the file specified in the src attribute. Now your server script doesn't have a route for that. It will load the css if you add a route for that specific css file. However as Irshad said,  the standard way to do this is to add a route for all the static files.

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

Right now,  you are only sending home.html everytim the root is requested.

Change your code to read the requested file from the req and serve that file whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the middleware to serve static files (css, html) from public folder `app.use(express.static("public"))`

[See the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xppnzoon9z?fontsize=14)